# CSS - Align right hand margin to tooltip paragraph that line breaks automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, tooltip

With or without a set width, how can I make the right hand margin properly align to my tooltip paragraphs?

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZne.jpg)

[How I'd like the tooltip to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcwCC.jpg)

In this example I've set the width as 190px so the paragraph wraps at "descriptions" which is okay, but it leaves a large gap behind on the right hand side. Is it at all possible to set a width but have the right hand margin align right to the text? I'm not sure how to line break automatically without setting a width but I can't see my problem going away while a width is set.

I've been trying to get this right for many days now and the best workaround I've come up with is setting a width and using `text-align: justify` or `text-align: center` but I would prefer to keep it aligned to the left.

You can see in my JSFiddle below how default tooltips work within Leaflet. There's no set width for them in the [Leaflet CSS](https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css) and the `.leaflet-tooltip` section includes `white-space: nowrap` so they weren't designed for such but for the few place markers I'd like to add descriptions, info or sources to, it would be nice to have them looking their best. Also in the Leaflet CSS are:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
position: absolute;
padding: 6px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #222;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
pointer-events: none;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Questions similar to mine I'd found when searching were all too different that their answers wouldn't work for my code or were too complex for me to understand. I've tried many different properties and values but without luck - perhaps I was doing something wrong. I didn't think I would still be scratching my head over this though so please check out the JFiddle and play around with it and hopefully advise if you're able. Thank you

Sorry if I'm using any words incorrectly! Still pretty new to all this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw61bps5/) *please click "Irving" in the top, right control box for markers to appear*

Comment: The width of the text 'descriptions' is greater than the remaining space on right. It can't occupy that space.
Hence it goes on to a newline. You may need to use `word-break: break-all;` to break the word to fit there. But it is not proper for reading.

Comment: @spirit Yes I understand the width of the text "descriptions" is greater than the width set, but I'm asking if there's a way I can have the remaining space on the right move inwards to the text, whether it's by setting the width a different way or something else. I've tried `word-break: break-all` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw61bps5/1/) but I was hoping I could do better.

Answer (score 0):

so, although the tooltip itself is not restricted with a `width` property, the contained `p` element is.

The paragraph element is a *block* element, which means that it is essentially a **rectangle** inside of which its contents are wrapped in different ways depending on the properties applied.

In this case the paragraph is set to a fixed 190px, which means that if at least one line's characters do not add up to precisely 190px they would wrap in a different way.

So, you can choose between the following alternatives:

- as it has been already proposed in the comments, change the `word-break` property to `word-break: break-all`
- change your text-alignment to `text-align:justify`
- remove the fixed width and apply `display:inline` and `float:left` on the paragraph element, but with unpredictable results concerning the number of lines of the content.

Well, that's about it. In order to target the paragraph element use the class `.leaflet-tooltip p`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and your description of the issue, but unless I'm missing something [none of those alternatives look desirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlAbU.jpg). The third option wraps at the text of "Glenzierbeck Knowe" which isn't in the p element but inside the tooltip. If I add it to the p element then it will just wrap at the longest word in the tooltip. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @Matthew88 You are welcome. As I said, there is no definitive solution to your problem, but rather selecting the _least worse_ solution to your problem. Since you can alter the html as well, what I would do would be to place the title in its own `p` element, give it a class and apply `white-space:nowrap` on it. So, the title would be left intact and the description paragraph would wrap based on the title.

Comment: @Matthew88 being 20 years in the field I have to tell you this. Don't bother with details of this kind. No-one will notice/bother/praise. It's so insignificant I would leave it as it was initially. Your should only spend time to learn new things and learn how to think in other ways, but that's about it. Keep in mind that good design is always subjective - I actually like the _flaw_ in its initial implementation - largest margin and all.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It is only myself who would be viewing it anyway, I just wanted to perfect this tooltip to go with the map I've been building (and perfecting, which has taught me a lot). I'll probably settle for the initial implementation then. I just thought I had to be missing something on getting that right margin to adapt though. I'm surprised there's no way it can be done. Thanks for your time and insight!

Comment: @Matthew88 You are welcome. Giving some credit by accepting the answer would be great!